# Is there an envelope class in shapely?

Tags: python, geometry, geos, jts, shapely

I found the [envelope class](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Envelope.html) in Java's JTS library very handy. An envelope holds the minimal and maximal coordinates of a geometry and is also called *bounding box* sometimes.

I wanted to get the common envelope of a number of shapely points. In JTS you could call *expandToInclude* to enlarge the envelope point by point.

As JTS was serving as a blueprint to GEOS / [shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/), I was expecting something similar in shapely, but could not find it (I am new to the library though). I know it is no rocket science to do it yourself, but I doubt there is no more elegant way to do this. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there's no envelope class in Shapely, which relies on (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) tuples. If you wanted to program in the same JTS style, it would be trivial to write an envelope class wrapping such a tuple.

Another option:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
print MultiPoint(points).bounds
```

Answer (score 27):

To create simple box geometries, there is a `box` function that returns a rectangular polygon:

```
from shapely.geometry import box
# box(minx, miny, maxx, maxy, ccw=True)
b = box(2, 30, 5, 33)
b.wkt  # POLYGON ((5 30, 5 33, 2 33, 2 30, 5 30))
b.area  # 9.0
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone coming here, [`shapely Polygon`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#polygons) has now `bounds` which I believe is equivalent to JTS `envelop`. Following is the documentation from official page

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
polygon = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
polygon.bounds
(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```

> Its x-y bounding box is a (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) tuple.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone new coming here, `shapely` *does* have an `envelope` function (if I understand the original correctly). This requires you to create a `MultiPoint` object of a minimum of 2 points.

```
MultiPoint([(0, 0), (1, 1)]).envelope
```

> <POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))>

See here: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.envelope

> Returns a representation of the point or smallest rectangular polygon (with sides parallel to the coordinate axes) that contains the object.